# encode/decode Query String ReturnUrl Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am sending the return url as a query string parameter like this `http://localhost:50316/TripNestFinal/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=~/Account/AccountSettings.aspx`

But i want `~/Account/AccountSettings.aspx` to be encoded in such a way so that i can

1. `encode/decode` in `jQuery/javascript`
2. `encode/decode` in `VB.NET`
3. `encode` in `VB.NET` and `decode` in `javascript/jQuery` and vice versa

This doesn't have to be bulletproof as i am not dealing with security here. All i want to do is to change this `~/Account/AccountSettings.aspx` to something that does not show the path directly.

I thought of using `Base64` encoding but when i `Base64` Encode , it includes a `'/'` character which breaks my jQuery logic. Is there any way i can avoid the `'/'` character when i `Base64` encode?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to URL encode the Base64 encoded string, that will work - although you'll need to check the generated query string length to make sure it doesn't hit the .NET maximum.

But I have to ask why you'd want to encode it in this way?